# How to enable Core Data Encryption on SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

When we are dealing with an UIKit project containing a delegate we just need to add this code

```
do {
    // Define Options
    let options: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
        NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey: FileProtectionType.complete
    ]

    // Add Persistent Store
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                                      configurationName: nil,
                                                      at: persistentStoreURL,
                                                      options: options)
} catch {
    // Error Handling
    ...
}
```

To have encryption enabled for Core Data.

But how to do that, when you have a SwiftUI app, **WITHOUT A DELEGATE** that only contains a file called `Persistense.swift`containing this:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
      return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TharmaTrack")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

????

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NSPersistentContainer` has an array of `persistentStoreDescriptions`, which you can modify before calling `container.loadPersistentStores`. In fact, you already do this to change the store’s URL if `inMemory` is true.

So to set the file protection option:

```
container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TharmaTrack")
container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.setOption(FileProtectionType.complete as NSObject,
                                                       forKey: NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey)
```